# Java random number generation

Tags: java

How generate random number according to some statics table .like need number between 1 to 6. Chances of getting 1 is 30%, chances of getting 2 is 25% and chances of getting 6 is 10% etc..

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763015/java-how-do-i-generate-a-random-number-that-is-weighted-towards-certain-number

Comment: Generate random number from 1 to 100, then use condition, if from 1 to 10 then choose 6 ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a method to do this. You must create it.For example:

```
static int generateRandom(){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int number = rnd.nextInt(100);
    if(number<30){
        //30% chance to return 1
        return 1;
    }else if(number<30+25){
        //25% chance to return 2
        return 2;
    }else if(number<30+25+10){
        //10% chance to return 6
        return 6;
    }else{
        //45% chance to return 3
        return 3;
    }
}
```